# How can I make a search bar that does not have rounded corners in css that will work on google chrome?

Tags: css, searchbar

I am designing a website and I would like the search bar to not have rounded corners-just the typical straight corners. For whatever reason I cannot make it work in google chrome, but when I pull up my website in firefox it does have straight corners. Does anyone know what I need to do so the search bar will show up in chrome without rounded corners?

Here is my css:

```
#searchbar {
float:right;
padding:10px 20px;
clear:right;
margin-right:35px;
margin-top:-7px;
}

#searchbar input {
float:right;
border:1px solid #000;
border-radius:none;
}

#searchbar p {
margin:5px 10px 0 0;
float:right;
text-transform:capitalize;
font-variant:small-caps;
font-size:1em;
}
```

Comment: suggest that you make a fiddle of this and post the link. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you must have an overriding css rule in there, because this will create an input with squared edges.  Can you post the rest of your css  http://jsfiddle.net/LjDq8/

Comment: Read this article about [styling html5 search inputs](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/), you should find enough info in there, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your css. This will change the default showing of a search to be the same as text-field which has straight corners. http://jsfiddle.net/8PdDt/

```
input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}​​​
```